# Animation Scroll With Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following code from my website.

```
<section id="hp-performance" class="hp-performance">
                    <h2 class="hidden">Our Numbers Proven Performance</h2>
                    <div class="performance-wrap" data-background-attachment-rollback id="refresh">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="textwidget custom-html-widget">
                                <div class="performance-title site-section-title">
                                    <span style="font-size: 70px">
                                        <strong class="performance-section-number site-section-  number">04</strong>
                                        Τα ακινητα <b>που διαθετουμε</b>
                                        <i class="title-line" style="left: -120px;"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <ul class="performance-list">
                                    <li class="fast">
                                        <span>$<i>2</i>+B</span>Total Sales<br>Since 2015
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span><i>135</i>K</span>Total Email<br>Subscribers
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span><i>44</i></span>Number of<br>Agents
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span><i>760</i></span>Transactions since<br>2015
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
```

When I load the full page from the site, this section loads numbers with effect. But if I don't reload the page, this effect does not work and the numbers are the statics. How can I add an effect and every time I scroll upper or down this section the numbers reload and see the effect again?

I used the onscroll event but this doesn't work.

```
<script>
var div=getElementById("refresh")
div.addEventListener('scroll', () = > {div.load(document.URL + " #refresh")})
</script>


SCRIPT FROM THIS ANIMATION MAYBE IS:


ourNumbersProvenPerformance: function () {
            var performanceEl = $('.hp-performance .performance-wrap .performance-list');
            var speed = 0;
            performanceEl.elementPeek({
                onViewportIn: function (object) {
                    
                    if (!performanceEl.hasClass('done-calculation')) {
                        object.addClass('done-calculation');

                        performanceEl.find('li span i').each(function (index, value) {
                            
                            if ($(this).parent().parent().hasClass('fast')) {
                                speed = 300;      
                            }else{
                                speed = 1000;
                            }

                            // console.log(speed);

                            var _this = $(this),
                                value = _this.text();

                            _this.animateNumber({
                                number: value
                            }, speed);
                        });
                    }
                },
                peekAmountToTrigger: 0.1
            });
        },
        
        ipMarketingGlobalExposureNumbers: function () {
            var performanceEl = $('.page-template-template-marketing-list .ip-marketing-global-exposure-numbers');

            performanceEl.elementPeek({
                onViewportIn: function (object) {
                    if (!performanceEl.hasClass('done-calculation')) {
                        object.addClass('done-calculation');

                        performanceEl.find('div.ip-marketing-global-exposure-numbers-item span em').each(function (index, value) {
                            var _this = $(this),
                                value = _this.text();

                            _this.animateNumber({
                                number: value
                            }, 1000);
                        });
                    }
                },
                peekAmountToTrigger: 0.1
            });

            jQuery(".page-template-template-marketing-list .hp-performance .performance-wrap .performance-list li").chainHeight({
                breakpoints: [
                    {
                        min: 321,
                    }
                ]
            });
        },

"I dont know this syntax (name: function() {})"
```

Answer (score 0):

Without digging too much through the specific animation code, perhaps it would be easier to remove/add the class that is being used to trigger it?

```js
// Also... maybe double-check that this is the element being scrolled
var div = document.getElementById("refresh");

div.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  $("#refresh .performance-list").removeClass("performance-list").addClass("performance-list");
}, false);
```

(replace `$` with `jQuery` if you are using something with `jQuery.noConflict()`)

Also, a note on your code. It looks like you are trying to use .load() to load a file into an HTML div, but .load() in this sense is a jQuery method. That is, you can't do div.load() if div is just an HTML element, but you can do something like:

```js
var div = $("refresh");
div.on('scroll', () = > {div.load(document.URL + " #refresh")});
```